# failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 5

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm a beginner to PHP and the Facebook API. I want a upload an image to facebook. I get an error that says: `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`

Below is a sample of my code:

```
    <?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); $app_id="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" ; $app_secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ; $my_url="`http://localhost/facebook/examples/example.php`" ; $perms_str="publish_stream" ; $code=$ _REQUEST[ "code"]; if(empty($code)) { $auth_url="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url). "&scope=" . $perms_str; echo( "<script>top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>"); } $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url).
    "&client_secret=" . $app_secret. "&code=" . $code; $response=f ile_get_contents($token_url); $p=n ull; parse_str($response, $p); $access_token=$ p[ 'access_token']; $graph_url="https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?" . "access_token=" .$access_token; if (!empty($_FILES))
    { $params=a rray(); if( isset($_POST[ 'message']) ) { $params[ 'message']=t rim($_POST[ 'message']); } $uploaddir='./uploads/' ; // Upload folder $uploadfile=$ uploaddir . basename($_FILES[ 'source'][ 'name']); if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[ 'source'][
    'tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) { $params[ 'source']="@" . realpath($uploadfile); } // Start the Graph API call $ch=c url_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$graph_url); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); curl_setopt($ch,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params); $result=c url_exec($ch); $decoded=j son_decode($result, true); curl_close($ch); if(is_array($decoded) && isset($decoded[ 'id'])) { $msg="Image uploaded successfully: {$decoded['id']}" ; } } 
?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <title>Upload</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <?php if( isset($msg) ) { ?>
      <p id="msg">
        <?php echo $msg; ?>
      </p>
      <?php } ?>
      <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
        <p>
          <label for="name">Caption</label>
          <input type="text" name="message" value="" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="source">Image</label>
          <input type="file" name="source" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </p>
      </form>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: please reformat your code. it's basically unreadable right now. yo u ha ve sp a ces all ov er. But you ARE double-encoding your urls, which is probably half of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra quotes in $my_url

```
$my_url="http://localhost/facebook/examples/example.php"
```